# Query SQL Database with Scala

Tags: sql, database, scala, h2

I am trying to do a basic query of an existing H2 database. My connection works fine and I'm able to get some data back, but the data is odd and I can't actually get a column from a table. Here's my code:

```
import java.sql.{Connection, DriverManager, ResultSet}; // Import necessary SQL libraries

class H2 {

  val connection_string = "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost//tmp/UXDemo;user=sa;password=admin"

  Class.forName("org.h2.Driver")  // Make a call to H2 Driver so it can be used

  def read = {

    // Create a Connection Object
    val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connection_string)

    try {

      // Ensure SQL Statements are Read-Only
      val statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)

      // Execute Given SQL Query
      val results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM \"event\"")

      while (results.next()) {
        println(results)
      }

    } finally {

      connection.close

    }


  }

}
```

When I run this, it compiles fine and I get this in return:

```
s0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 0
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 1
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 2
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 3
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 4
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 5
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 6
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 7
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 8
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 9
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 10
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 11
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 12
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 13
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 14
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 15
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 16
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 17
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 18
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 19
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 20
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 21
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 22
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 23
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 24
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 25
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 26
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 27
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 28
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 29
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 30
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 31
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 32
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 33
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 34
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 35
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 36
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 37
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 38
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 39
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 40
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 41
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 42
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 43
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 44
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 45
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 46
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 47
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 48
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 49
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 50
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 51
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 52
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 53
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 54
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 55
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 56
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 57
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 58
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 59
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 60
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 61
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 62
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 63
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 64
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 65
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 66
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 67
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 68
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 69
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 70
rs0: columns: 6 rows: 72 pos: 71
```

I tried to actually `SELECT` from a column, but it says that the column doesn't exist, so I stripped it out and wanted to see what the bare results were and they didn't make much sense. Is there something I'm missing in my code or is it an H2 configuration issue?

Comment: Did you try something like results.getString?

Comment: So I added `results.getString()` and put the column name `text` as the string and it came back correct. However, when I query the column as `SELECT text FROM "event"` I get an error that it doesn't exist. Do I always need to query everything with `SELECT * FROM "event"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the issue. The column names in H2 (at least in this case) require quotes around them. By adding quotes I was able to query the individual column. When I originally tried this, it didn't work, likely because of a typo so I switched to triple quotes in the executeQuery params. You also need .getString() as @Ashalynd recommended so that it outputs strings.

```
val results = statement.executeQuery(""" SELECT "text" FROM "event" """)

      while (results.next) {
        println(results.getString("text"))
      }
```